# lowest melting point of alkali salts

Tags: electrochemistry, melting-point, salt, alkali-metals

I want to make the alkali metals sodium and potassium through electrolysis of molten salts. However, I only have the ability to heat stuff up to about 260 degrees Celsius.
What would be the lowest melting point salts of sodium and potassium that could be used for this purpose?

Answer (score 3):

Instead of halides, consider hydroxides A eutectic of sodium hand potassium hydroxides melts at 170°C. See:

Sergei Devyatkin. "Interaction of Oxides and Molten Alkalis, Products of Reaction and Application", *Sustainable Industrial Processing Summit & Exhibition, Volume 7: Ionic Liquids & Energy Production*, Edited by Florian Kongoli, Flogen, 2015, p. 237.

Comment: Is there a similar substance that exists as a pure substance? (not a mixture). I want pure sodium or pure potassium.

Comment: @user16791137 And you somehow didn't think about eutectic of two or more sodium salts?

Comment: @mithoron I am finding your suggestion hard to get by searching, so if you know something do tell. It does seem that NaCl+NaOH does not go below 260°C because the eutectic composition has too much NaOH, and I can't imagine any other binary more likely to succeed.

Comment: Maybe sodium tetrachloroaluminate would work.

Comment: It would. But I hesitate, because electrolyzing it could deposit aluminum instead of the alkali metal.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Molten-salt_battery#Na-NiCl2

Comment: So, put it in as your answer. I am done, I do not want to be dinged about moving this to chat.